# How to store value inside ChannelHandlerContext netty 4.1.50

Tags: java, netty

I'm using netty 4.1.50 and I would like to identify the connection with a username.

I found this method (which works perfectly):

```java
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object message) {
    ctx.attr(AttributeKey.valueOf("nickname")).set("amazingNickName");
    System.out.println(ctx.attr(AttributeKey.valueOf("nickname")).get());
    ctx.attr(AttributeKey.valueOf("nickname")).remove();
    System.out.println(ctx.attr(AttributeKey.valueOf("nickname")).get());
}
```

The output:

```
amazingNickName
null
```

But according to my IDE, it is deprecated and I should no longer use this method, I did not find an example with an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ctx.channel.attr(...)` as a replacement for your use-case

Comment: Use ctx.channel().attr(...)